# How to access sensitive keys in deployed Reactjs + Supabase app

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, azure-pipelines, supabase

So I have a React + Supabase project that is being deployed with Azure DevOps, I'm completely new to deploying apps on Azure, I'm only familiar with Vercel/Cloudflare so forgive me if I'm way off in anything I say here.

From what I can see, I can successfully host the app, however the Supabase client can't be created because I have no idea how to securely read the Supabase keys once it's deployed. I've read that the URL and anon key can be public due to RLS, but the Service key should not be shown publicly. I use all three in my app, and just thought it'd be easier to make them all secrets in an Azure Key Vault, and then include the vault in my YAML file. Here's the YAML file I have atm:

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
  uiSource: 'src'
  uiBuild: 'build'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'My Service Connection'
    KeyVaultName: 'MyVault'
    SecretsFilter: '*'
    RunAsPreJob: true

- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    pushd $(uiSource)
    npm install
    npm run build
    popd
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
  
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(uiBuild)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

In the logs, it says it downloads the keys successfully, but now how can I read those keys in my React app? Is this even possible because React is creating the supabase client side? When going to the hosted URL, it errors cause the supabaseUrl cannot be found.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.